# Why does Improper Integral Diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

[image]

Hello,
I don't really understand so well why this integral diverges.  I tried expanding $e^x$ by its Taylor Series around infinity, but I don't really know how to.  I typed in, in Wolfram Alpha, Taylor Series of $e^x$ at x is equal to infinity and it says does not exist.  Is this why the integral diverges?

Comment: problem is not about $x\to\infty$, but when $x\to 0$. Integral behaves like $1/x$ and diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near $0$, $1/(e^x-1)$ is approximately $1/x$; indeed $1/(e^x-1)-1/x$
is bounded on the interval $[0,1]$. But $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x}$ is divergent, so $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{e^x-1}$ is also divergent.

Comment: But my integrand is from 0 to infinity not 0 to 1.

Comment: @kemb the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ is convergent; it's at zero that the integral diverges.

Comment: Got it.  I understand.  I just don't know by looking at the problem, how I would know that 1/(e^x-1) is approximately 1/x.  What is the intuition behind this?  Thanks.

Comment: @kemb $e^x-1=x+x^2/2+\cdots$ is approximately $x$ for $x$ near zero.

Comment: Oh i see.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the problem of the antiderivative
$$I=\int \frac{dx}{e^x-1}=-\int \frac{e^x-1-e^x}{e^x-1}\,dx=-\int dx+\int\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}\,dx=-x+\log(e^x-1)$$ When $x\to \infty$, $I\to 0$ but when $x\to \epsilon$ $(\epsilon >0$ being small), $I \to -\epsilon+\log(e^\epsilon-1)$.

I am sure that you see the problem when $\epsilon \to 0^+$.
$$J=\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{dx}{e^x-1}=-\log (\epsilon )+\frac{\epsilon }{2}-\frac{\epsilon ^2}{24}+O\left(\epsilon
   ^4\right)$$